# Program keeps displaying None even after input

Tags: python

The code is meant to be a simple login code that saves the login information to a .txt file and then when logging in reads the text file to check the user details.

The code runs up until I create an account or try to login and put in my username and password then it comes back with None. I don't understand why it's coming back with None

```
def AskAccount():
    account = input("\nDo you have an account setup 
    already? (Y/N)\n")
    if account == "Y":
        loginexisting()
    elif account == "N":
        createacc()
    else:
        print("please type Y or N")
        AskAccount()

def loginexisting():
    print("Your account already exists, please login\n")
    username = input("Please enter your username:")
    password = input("Please enter your password:")

    f = open('accounts.txt', 'r')
    info = f.read()
    info = info.split()
    if username in info:
        index= info.index(username) +1
        usr_password = info[index]
    if usr_password == password:
        return "Welcome Back," + username
    else:
        return "password entered is wrong"
else:
    print("Username is not correct")
    print(createacc())


def createacc():
    print("Lets create an account for you\n")
    username = input("Please input your username:\n")
    password = input("please input your password\n")
    f = open("accounts.txt",'r')
    info = f.read()
    if username in info:
    return "Name Unavailable. Please Try Again"
    f.close()

    f = open("accounts.txt",'w')
    info = info + " " + username + " " + password
    f.write(info)
    f.close()

    print("Your account details have been saved\n")
    print("please login\n")


print(AskAccount())
```

Comment: You should decide whether your functions will `return` the strings and have the caller print them, or `print` the strings so the caller doesn't have to -- don't try to mix and match! 
 `createacc()` returns a string some of the time and does a `print` and implicit `return None` the rest of the time; whenever it returns `None`, `print(createacc())` will print `None`.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your file, you `print(AskAccount())`. This prints the *return value* of the function, but `AskAccount` does not have a return statement, thus it returns `None`. If you want it to print your desired output, you will need to add return statements.

```
def AskAccount():
    account = input("\nDo you have an account setup 
    already? (Y/N)\n")
    if account == "Y":
        return loginexisting()
    elif account == "N":
        return createacc()
    else:
        print("please type Y or N")
        return AskAccount()
```